# lavaan: Correlation between each pair of variables

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I have several variables, say `X1` to `Xn`, and I want to include correlation between each pair of them in my SEM (I use `lavaan` package for R software).

I know I can specify

```
X1 ~~ X2+X3+...+Xn
X2 ~~ X3+X4+...+Xn
X3 ~~ X4+X5+...+Xn
```

and so on.

Is there any shorter way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to create the calls, you could try this:

```
sub("\\+",  " ~~ ", sapply(1:10, function(i) paste(paste0("X", i:10), collapse = " + ")))

 [1] "X1  ~~  X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7 + X8 + X9 + X10" "X2  ~~  X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7 + X8 + X9 + X10"     
 [3] "X3  ~~  X4 + X5 + X6 + X7 + X8 + X9 + X10"           "X4  ~~  X5 + X6 + X7 + X8 + X9 + X10"               
 [5] "X5  ~~  X6 + X7 + X8 + X9 + X10"                     "X6  ~~  X7 + X8 + X9 + X10"                         
 [7] "X7  ~~  X8 + X9 + X10"                               "X8  ~~  X9 + X10"                                   
 [9] "X9  ~~  X10"                                         "X10"
```

Perhaps you may want to delete the last element, `"X10"`, and of course you could replace `10` by the `N` of your data.

Comment: Thank you. I hoped for a single command to include those correlations in model. But this is better than nothing ;)